# Reactjs, TypeScript & Webpack on SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx-webparts, typescript, reactjs, webpack

I know that Reactjs, TypeScript & Webpack can be used on SharePoint Online to create web-parts. But can it be possible to create web-parts for SharePoint 2013 on premise. Please let me know if it possible.

If so please provide some article for it

**Update**
As I am getting lot of answer about SPFx, I am totally aware that SPFx only available on SP 2016 onwards and SP online. My concern is can we **Reactjs, TypeScript & Webpack on SharePoint2013 onpremise**

Comment: What ever you use to create solution, what is the final out come of the solution? Is it simple html, js, css then upload to site assets and refer html file in your pages with proper references of your js, css files. If outcome is something different then check SharePoint is capable of handling items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint framework works only on SharePoint online and SharePoint 2016 on-premise : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

Having said that, you can still write typescript code, bundle it and use as client side code in your 2013 on premise env also : https://sii.pl/blog/creating-sharepoint-solutions-with-typescript/

https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/utilizing-typescript-with-sharepoint-2013-javascript-object-model/

Comment: I am not asking about SPFx, but if you see my question title than I am just concern about Reactjs, TypeScript & Webpack on SP 2013 onpremise

Answer (score 2):

As Vipul Kelkar mentioned in his 2nd paragraph, you can perfectly use that development stack with SharePoint 2013. You can use whatever front-end framework you like. However, you cannot use the SPFx template. You need to build your own react / typescript / webpack configuration and a way to deploy your code.

In the end the toolstack just builds you a javascript file that you can host in a script editor webpart or content editor webpart. Or you could build a custom master page or page layout to fit your needs.

Comment: Just saw this link posted on twitter today. Seems to be exactly what you are looking for: https://collab365.community/events/under-the-hood-13-modern-development-with-marc-anderson/?utm_source=collab365&utm_medium=collab365today&utm_campaign=daily_digest

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the SharePoint FrameWork (SPFx) is only available to SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016 SP2.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40217.sharepoint-server-2016-sharepoint-framework-spfx.aspx

However, if you want to create a JS webpart as a content editor webpart, nothing prevents you from doing just that. I have already created a VueJS webpart in a SharePoint 2013 environment. You lose some OOTB features though, like webpart properties, webpart type to choose in the webpart picker, etc.

But you can recreate them with custom lists and js development and webpart templates that load the correct script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not asking about SPFx, but if you see my question title than I am just concern about Reactjs, TypeScript & Webpack on SP 2013 onpremise

Comment: TypeScript and Webpack are just for development purposes. When you're development is ready, you package it as html/css/js files, which you can then integrate in any webserver. As SharePoint allows you to integrate html files as webparts (content editor webpart), you can develop through any means you want and then integrate your compiled files in SP2013